# what does that mean for Text.hashCode() & Interger.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: hadoop

Recently, I am reading the definitive guide of hadoop.
I have two questions:

1.I saw a piece of code of one custom Partitioner:

```
public class KeyPartitioner extends Partitioner<TextPair, Text>{

    @Override
    public  int getPartition(TextPair key, Text value, int numPartitions){
        return (key.getFirst().hashCode()&Interger.MAX_VALUE)%numPartitions;
    }
}
```

what does that mean for &Integer.MAX_VALUE? why should use & operator?

2.I also want write a custom Partitioner for IntWritable. So is it OK and best for key.value%numPartitions directly?

Comment: `&` is a bitwise AND.

Comment: @MarounMaroun yes, I know, so they use hashcode to And max_value to keep the hashcode below the max_value?

Comment: To keep it positive, because negative partitions are obviously nonsense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like I already wrote in the comments, it is used to keep the resulting integer positive.

Let's use a simple example using Strings:

```
String h = "Hello I'm negative!";
int hashCode = h.hashCode();
```

`hashCode` is negative with the value of `-1937832979`.

If you would `mod` this with a positive number (>0) that denotes the partition, the resulting number is always negative.

```
System.out.println(hashCode % 5); // yields -4
```

Since partitions can never be negative, you need to make sure the number is positive. Here comes a simple bit twiddeling trick into play, because `Integer.MAX_VALUE` has all-ones execpt the sign bit (MSB in Java as it is big endian) which is only 1 on negative numbers.

So if you have a negative number with the sign bit set, you will always `AND` it with the zero of the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is always going to be zero.

You can make it more readable though:

```
return Math.abs(key.getFirst().hashCode() % numPartitions);
```

For example [I have done that in Apache Hama's partitioner](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hama/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/hama/bsp/HashPartitioner.java?view=markup) for arbitrary objects:

```
 @Override
 public int getPartition(K key, V value, int numTasks) {
    return Math.abs(key.hashCode() % numTasks);
 }
```

Comment: Cool explanation! +1 from my side.